# Java plugin crashing in Firefox - Fedora 20

Tags: fedora, java, firefox, plugin

I have been wrestling with this for over a day now. I have a Fedora 20 physical system running Firefox 38.0.5. When I go to the java site to verify my version I get an error saying "The Java plugin has crashed". My version of java is at the latest.

```
Name        : jre1.8.0_60
Version     : 1.8.0_60
Release     : fcs
Architecture: x86_64
```

I also have the latest JDK installed:

```
yum list installed *java*
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Installed Packages
java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64                                  :1.8.0.45-40.b14.fc20                                     
java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless.x86_64                          1:1.8.0.45-40.b14.fc20
```

And more info here:

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
```

The plugin in Firefox shows: (this is from the "about:plugins" in FF)

```
Java(TM) Plug-in 11.60.2

File: libnpjp2.so
Path: /usr/lib64/mozilla/plugins/libnpjp2.so
Version: 11.60.2
State: Enabled
Next Generation Java Plug-in 11.60.2 for Mozilla browsers
```

I have done the following:

Removed, re-installed Java.
Removed, re-installed FF. 
Tried different Java versions. 
Tried Opera.

I am not sure what to try next. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Fedora 20 is no longer maintained. Have you tried upgrading to a supported release?

Comment: That is something I can try but it will have to wait until this weekend.

Comment: Updated to FC 22. Still same problem in Firefox.

Comment: It is the only site you tested the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Kali Linux/Iceweasel. I just updated Java to Version 8/Update 65 and it fixed it. Apparently Update 60 had an issue.